# Retrofit creating mocked void success response?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

Hi i am trying to mock one of my request response api to return a response success of type Void but i cant seem to do that as Void cannot be initialised and is private.

Im trying to do this:V

```
val responseMock = Response.success(Void())
```

But no joy.

I even tried setting the Response.success(null) and it complains that the responseMock object has to be of type Void in my case as my api method  returns this:

```
Single<Response<Void>>
```

but having response.success(null) yields

```
Single<Response<Nothing?>>?
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If defined in Kotlin, `Single<Response<Void>>` is an impossible type. `Void` can only be `null` so the type has to be `Single<Response<Void?>>` to make `Response.success<Void?>(null)` a valid value.

Comment: diddnt work. it says "expected Single<Response<Void?>> but was Single<Response<>Nothing>

Comment: You just need to specify the generic type in the property declaration then, edited the answer to include it.